# Searching substrings

Tags: c++, substring

I am a programming student. I have been asked to write a program that searches for a substring of another string, but I am not suppose to use the `find()` function that is provided in the string class. The code I have written thus far works, but it uses the `find()` function. How can I change this to not use the find function and still give me the location of the substring? Here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    int f_r(string, string);
    int main()
    {
        string s;
        string t;
        cout << "\nEnter the string to be searched: ";
        getline(cin,s);
        cout << "Now enter the string you want to search for: ";
        cin >> t;
        if (f_r(s,t) == 0)
        {
            cout << "\n Substring could not be found.";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nThe index of substring is =  " << f_r(s,t) << endl;
        }
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }

    int f_r(string str, string c)
    {
        int pos = 0;
        pos = str.find(c, pos);
        if (pos > str.length())
        {
           return 0;
        }
        else
        {
           pos++;
           return pos - 1;
        }

     }
```

Comment: Have you tried to write a replacement to the `find` function yourself?  If so, what have you written?

Comment: By the way, I'm sure you have learned this, but one of the best algorithms for pattern matching is Rabin-Karp.  You can read about it on wikipidia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

You need to search for matches within the string ***ONE character at a time***, i.e. seeing the strings as if they were arrays of characters (since you're apparently working in C/C++ that is quite convenient since `string` and `char[]` are synonymous).

You will likely need to maintain indexes or pointers into the current location in both strings..

This will be the naive / initial approach, and when you get that working rather well, assuming you are a bit curious, you'll start wondering if there are more efficient ways of doing so, for example by skipping some characters in some cases, or by using general statistics about text in the underlying languages.

Answer (score 0):

This art may help:

```
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
     ^   ^
     i  i+j 
         | 
    |_|_|_|_| 
         ^
         j
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int search(char *a,char *b)
{
  int i=0,j=0,k=0,m,n,pos;
  m=strlen(a);
  n=strlen(b);
  while(1)
  {
    while((a[i]==b[j]) && b[j]!=0)
   {
     i++;
     j++;    
   }
   if (j==n)
   {
     pos=i-j;
     return(pos);
   }
   else
  {
     i=i-j+1;
     j=0;
  }
}}
```

I have this code with me. I hope it will help you.

Note:- its an old code

Comment: Typically we avoid giving complete solutions when the OP's question hints at the fact that this homework or some study-related concern.

Comment: Actually, I just noted that the solution isn't as _complete_ as it seems: There are a few bugs, in particular the lack of an explicit return when the string isn't found, unused variables and poor choice of variable names.  [sorry to be nitpicky, but if we're gonna help the next generation, let's give them an good example and good habits]

Comment: I am just showing the way for it. Just how to move around. Its just basic code. Thatsy I said "its an old code". BTW thanks for commenting I will remember it.